# 'Choose file' sidebar options disappeared

Tags: finder, google-chrome

When you go to a website with a file uploader you click on a `choose file` and a pop up window appears with a sidebar similar to what you have in your standard finder window, however recently all of the options like Documents, Downloads, Pictures etc are no longer present, now I can only see ak52-macbook and remote disk. In standard finder windows I have all my standard folders plus custom ones that I added. I made sure in finder preferences that all of them are displayed.

I could not find anything in the finder or chrome browser preferences regarding this so here is my question, how do I display all of those folder in the pick file to upload pop up sidebar?

Answer (score 1):

The kind of items in your case hidden are named **Favourites**. To show them, go to a site where you can upload a file (e.g. https://encodable.com/uploaddemo/) and then click on "`Choose File`", like you said. When you are prompted to upload something, just hover your cursor on the `Favourites` line, located on the top of the sidebar. A "`Show`" button will be shown (*no irony, at all*). Click it and all of the items will re-appear. Done!

If you have any more issues with this, feel free to comment.

Comment: I do not have my `favorites` hidden, the problem is that they are generally not there, here's a printscreen http://imgur.com/AM8ihoz